# What exactly does the loss value give while training a LSTM model in keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, loss-function

I have a LSTM model that predicts tomorrow's water outflow volume based on today's outflow volume, temperature, and precipitation.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=24, return_sequences=True, 
           input_shape=(X_Train.shape[1],X_Train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
history = model.fit(X_Train, Y_Train, epochs=8,
               validation_data=(X_Test, Y_Test))
```

[While training I got:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpMaG.png)

```
Epoch 1/8
4638/4638 [==============================] - 78s 17ms/step - loss: 
1.9951e-04 - val_loss: 1.5074e-04
Epoch 2/8
4638/4638 [==============================] - 77s 17ms/step - loss: 
9.6735e-05 - val_loss: 1.0922e-04
Epoch 3/8
4638/4638 [==============================] - 78s 17ms/step - loss: 
6.5202e-05 - val_loss: 5.9079e-05
Epoch 4/8
4638/4638 [==============================] - 77s 17ms/step - loss: 
5.1011e-05 - val_loss: 4.9478e-05
Epoch 5/8
4638/4638 [==============================] - 77s 17ms/step - loss: 
4.3992e-05 - val_loss: 5.1148e-05
Epoch 6/8
4638/4638 [==============================] - 77s 17ms/step - loss: 
3.9901e-05 - val_loss: 4.2351e-05
Epoch 7/8
4638/4638 [==============================] - 74s 16ms/step - loss: 
3.6884e-05 - val_loss: 4.0763e-05
Epoch 8/8
4638/4638 [==============================] - 74s 16ms/step - loss: 
3.5287e-05 - val_loss: 3.6736e-05
```

But when I manually calculate the mean-square error, I get a different result

```
mean_square_root = mean_squared_error(predicted_y_values_unnor, Y_test_actual)
130.755469707972
```

[Manual Calculation:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hLNQ.png)

I wanted to know why they would the validation loss be different while training than while calculating manually. How is the loss calculated while training?

Comment: How did you get `predicted_y_values_unnor` ?

Comment: In deep learning, generally normalized inputs are given (mean=0 and std-dev=1). That's why loss numbers are very tiny.

Comment: I get it now. I was comparing normalized loss with my unnormalized mean squared error.

Comment: Great. Glad to help you. Please accept the answer so that we are able to help others in the community.

Answer (score 1):

The loss you have chosen is `mean_squared_error` in the line

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

That is the loss your LSTM model is minimizing.

The Mean Squared Error, or MSE, loss is the default loss to use for regression problems. Mean squared error is calculated as the average of the squared differences between the predicted and actual values. The result is always positive regardless of the sign of the predicted and actual values and a perfect value is 0.0. The squaring means that larger mistakes result in more error than smaller mistakes, meaning that the model is punished for making larger mistakes.

LSTM is a general model and you can choose lots of different loss functions. Here is keras inbuilt available functions list
https://keras.io/api/losses/
You need to select a loss function as per your problem.

Comment: I calculated the average of the squared differences between the predicted and actual values using sklean mean_squared_error function on the test data. It differs from the validation loss while training hugely. The validation loss while training is in the range of 10^-5, while calculating mean squared errror using sklearn gives a value of 130.75. Am I comparing two different things?

Answer (score 1):

I was just having the same exact problem and i solved it with flatten() function.
When you do: "mean_squared_error(predicted_y_values_unnor, Y_test_actual)" the shape of "Y_test_actual" is just a one dimensional array. Example: array([297, 290, 308, 308, 214]) but the other argument is a bidimensional array in wich one of the dimensions is 1. Example: "array([300.53693, 299.9416 , 295.61334, 218.2563 , 219.74983],
dtype=float32)"

you just have to do flatten() on "predicted_y_values_unnor"